# How can I change the KDE Plasma lock screen theme?

Tags: kde, themes, lock-screen, customization

I have customized nearly everything I wanted and I think it looks perfect except for the lock screen.

I looked everywhere in the settings and there is no option to download a theme or make changes to the look (except for the wallpaper).

I downloaded an SDDM theme for the startup login screen and would like to make the lock screen match that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

settings --> Workspace behavior --> Screen Locking --> Appearance
[image]

An SDDM Theme is irrelevant if you do not logout.